Where can I check the voting date for the law?
Where can I find information about the voting date for the law regarding Bitcoin and the creation of a federal reserve based on Bitcoin in the United States? I am looking for details on when this legislation will be voted on. Is there a way to track upcoming votes on this bill, and are there any specific resources or official websites where I can monitor updates on its progress? I hope this is not off-topic for this forum.

If you're looking for information about the United States Congress, you can find official and up-to-date about pending legislation at Congress.gov.
You can see the full text, a summary, the sponsor, and scheduled actions for any bill under consideration in its current session, as well as very nearly every other legislative session since the nation was founded.
Searching for "Bitcoin," for instance, returns eight results, including S.4912, which I suspect is the bill you're talking about, as Senator Lummis has been out talking about it since the Fed made a public statement saying it could not buy Bitcoin under current law. The bill would establish a "Strategic Bitcoin Reserve" and require the Federal Reserve "to remit a certain amount of net earnings annually to the purchase of Bitcoins."
Given its current progress, it's virtually certain that this bill will not be enacted in this Congress.

Heh, the bill has a really strained retronym in its title: Boosting Innovation, Technology, and Competitiveness through Optimized Investment Nationwide Act of 2024

Note: IF not enacted this congress, the bill is moot and would have to be introduced as if anew.

Thank you for your response. This is exactly what I am looking for. I am not at all knowledgeable about the American legislative process. So could you please clarify how I can find out the date of the next vote on this bill?

Right now you can't, because there are no votes scheduled for the bill. The current session of Congress is basically done, so the bill is pretty much dead. It will likely be reintroduced next year, so you'll be able to start tracking votes then.
